# Search in PHP array full string match to string with wild card

Tags: php, arrays, match, wildcard

I have an array like:

```
$links = array('home', 'contact', 'profile/*', 'link1', 'link2');
```

Then I have a string like:

```
$current_url = 'profile/user1';
```

Is it possible to test if array `$links` contain `$current_url` without need to loop through `$links`
I know how to do that with loop and `fnmatch()` function, but I am trying to avoid loop if possible.
The problem here is that I want to match full string against string with wildcard.

Comment: How about [strpos](https://secure.php.net/strpos) ?

Comment: Does `$links` need to be an array, are they static or dynamically defined somehow? Would look into using regexp instead, something like this https://3v4l.org/octM2 That way you can define much more complex patterns and combinations of patterns besides just the `*` wildcard.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the variable use of the wildcard `*`?  Does it always mean a `non-slash`?  Might it mean a partial set of letters?  You will need to do some sort of looping -- either to build a regex pattern with pipes (iterating function) or use a foreach loop to check each element.  The best you can do in terms of performance is write an early `break` condition in your loop, or use an array function that halts as soon as it finds a match (like `array_search()`).  If this is a possible element: `'profile/*/links/*'` then you will need to order the elements with `rsort()` to prioritize.

Comment: it is possible to define even pattern instead of *. $links is always an array. Because the purpose is to define pages, visiting of which cause that user/owner will get notification. In this case I want to save notification that someone visited users profile, there will be also urls which will save notifications that someone liked profile, added as friend, sent message, etc. Rest of the things is based on $_GET variable key and value so its easy. But in this case its taking permalink which is a pagename/username. Based on $current_url match are then set rules what type of notification to save.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php) that extracts all the values of an array that respects a certain comparison function. This comparison function could test the wild card.

Like this:

```
$links = array('home', 'contact', 'profile/*', 'link1', 'link2');
$current_url = 'profile/user1';

function match($string) {
    // Check if $string matches $current_url
}
array_filter($links, "match");
```

And if `array_filter` contains something, the url had a match.

Comment: This answer is missing the critical processing portion to qualify as a truly helpful answer.  This post is better positioned as a comment on the question that says: "Have you tried using `array_filter()`?"  This answer is what I would have expected the OP to post in the question as a failed/incomplete attempt to self solve.